# JavaScript .onchange keeps flickering

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm making a simple timezone clock, and I made a dropdown list to choose the timezone.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let clock = document.getElementById("clock");
    let zoneTitle = document.getElementById("zoneTitle");

    

    function calcTime(city, offset) {
        var d = new Date();

        var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

        var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000 * offset));
        var nd = nd.toLocaleString().substr(10);
        zoneTitle.innerHTML = city;
        clock.innerHTML = nd;
    }
    
    function main(timeZone) {
        switch(timeZone) {
            case "EST":
            setInterval(function() {
                calcTime(timeZone, "-5");
            }, 1000);
            break;
            case "PST":
            setInterval(function() {
                calcTime(timeZone, "-8");
            }, 1000);
            break;
            case "CET":
            setInterval(function() {
                calcTime(timeZone, "+1");
            }, 1000);
            break;
            case "AST":
            setInterval(function() {
                calcTime(timeZone, "-4");
            }, 1000);
            break;
            case "AEST":
            setInterval(function() {
                calcTime(timeZone, "+10");
            }, 1000);
            break;
            
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("TimeZones").addEventListener("change", function() {
        main(document.getElementById("TimeZones").value);
    
    })
    

})
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="app.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Asap:wght@400;700&family=Space+Grotesk:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Clock Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="zoneTitle">TimeZone</h1>
    <h1 id="clock">Current Time</h1>

    <select name="time-zones" id="TimeZones">
        <option id="EST" value="EST" selected>EST - Eastern Standard Time</option>
        <option id="PST" value="PST">PST - Pacific Standard Time</option>
        <option value="CST">CST - Central Standard Time</option>
        <option value="AST">AST - Atlantic Standard Time</option>
        <option value="AEST">AEST - Australian Eastern Standard Time</option>
    </select>


</body>
</html>
```

It then runs through a switch statement to determine the timezone.
The problem I'm having is that whenever I select a new dropdown list item, it flickers between the item I just selected and all the previously selected items.

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: main is not defined",`  Where is `main()`?

Comment: It's likely a problem in `main`. Perhaps it's trying to set the value of the `select`? Or setting individual `option`s' `selected` properties?

Comment: You don't seem to define `main` here, so it'll obviously throw that error. Where are you defining main in your full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you never clear your intervals. Whenever the user changes the dropdown value, you create a new interval, but the previous ones keep running.

A solution would be to have an interval that is always running, and within you could have the logic for selecting the correct timezone.

Here is an example :

```js
let clock = document.getElementById("clock");
let zoneTitle = document.getElementById("zoneTitle");



function calcTime(city, offset) {
  let d = new Date();

  let utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

  let nd = new Date(utc + (3600000 * offset));
  let ndString = nd.toLocaleString().substr(10);
  zoneTitle.innerHTML = city;
  clock.innerHTML = ndString;
}

// Let's set up an object that will match a timezone string to the timezone offset
const offsets = {
  "EST": -5,
  "PST": -8,
  "CST": 1,
  "AST": -4,
  "AEST": 10,
}

// Now run the interval that will update the displayed date
setInterval(function() {
    let selectedTimezoneString = document.getElementById("TimeZones").value // Fetch the selected time zone
    calcTime(selectedTimezoneString, offsets[selectedTimezoneString]);
}, 1000);

// No need to create an event for the dropdown value change since we fetch it every second anyway
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="app.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Asap:wght@400;700&family=Space+Grotesk:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Clock Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="zoneTitle">TimeZone</h1>
    <h1 id="clock">Current Time</h1>

    <select name="time-zones" id="TimeZones">
        <option id="EST" value="EST" selected>EST - Eastern Standard Time</option>
        <option id="PST" value="PST">PST - Pacific Standard Time</option>
        <option value="CST">CST - Central Standard Time</option>
        <option value="AST">AST - Atlantic Standard Time</option>
        <option value="AEST">AEST - Australian Eastern Standard Time</option>
    </select>


</body>
</html>
```